# Recover XMO. ltc-xmo through changelly but in XMR wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery

So I Brought XMO thnking it was XMR on changelly and sent it to my XMR gui wallet i've contacted them they've said there's nothing they can do.

INPUT TRANSACTION HASH  9ef0d7abc97ae5460237b22809b55d255114bcf13cf84f6d1ea9e54f3bd981d6
AMOUNT  0.39838761 LTC
MONEY RECEIVED  21 May 2018, 14:26:54
FEE 0.121412592764 XMO
EXCHANGE RATE   1 LTC = 15.54281793 XMO
RECEIVER    42h2DQ7syPoZzc3b7BvCfzBoZrCqGBwamYWQQRjGeLgAHUuGeBU4rvu8cGzhSfooAxiDHkNdXmtATN1jvnd5X7EJPq3Yc27
OUTPUT TRANSACTION HASH 054be4b75828d9ca98da47cd3c3e898e1023d8bf9b5cc7852a5d2dc410befbc8
AMOUNT  6.16110576 XMO
MONEY SENT  21 May 2018, 14:47:10

I've tried renaming the gui folder like the guide but i'd done that before for another problem so this time didn't seem to reset the wallet. Is there a different way to re-set the wallet? Can I have XMO in my XMR wallet? I saw something about syncing to a different blockchain or something. Help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction is present only [in the XMO blockchain](https://minergate.com/blockchain/xmo/transaction/054be4b75828d9ca98da47cd3c3e898e1023d8bf9b5cc7852a5d2dc410befbc8), not [in XMR blockchain](https://blox.minexmr.com/search?value=054be4b75828d9ca98da47cd3c3e898e1023d8bf9b5cc7852a5d2dc410befbc8). You can't get XMR with a XMO transaction.

The upgrade guides won't help you since the cases tackled by those guide is for (1) outbound transaction mistakenly sent in XMO chain when it's meant for XMR, and (2) inbound XMR transaction not showing in wallet due to wallet syncing with XMO chain. You are asking for an inbound XMO transaction (post-fork) to be shown in XMR wallet. Since the transaction is not present in XMR chain, there is no way for you to receive XMR in this way.

Your best bet is to get a reputable exchange or cryptocurrency converting service that will accept XMO (or XMC; They are the same thing), and sell them for XMR. (That is, if you can find a reputable exchange for XMO at all; XMO is shady all along) You still need to download an XMO wallet to send your XMO out. Official XMR wallet v0.11.1 (Helium Hydra) theoretically works but I have never tried it.

And in case you still haven't realize, [avoid Changelly](https://www.reddit.com/r/monero/wiki/avoid).